# handling style in functional component in react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i am using a functional component, and have created a sidebar menu structure , with parent child way (kind of dropdown). So when I click on parent an active class should be toggle and on its next element toggle style> display> none/block.

```
        <Fragment key={index}>
          <button
            className='dropdown-btn bg-transparent haschild'
            style={{ border: 'none' }}
          >
            {data.name} <i className='fas fa-chevron-right'></i>
          </button>
          <div 
            className='dropdown-container'>
            <Content
              config={menuItem.children}
              children={true}
            />
          </div>
        </Fragment>
```

and on use effect

```
useEffect(() => {
   var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("haschild");
   var i;
   for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
     dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
       this.classList.toggle("active");
       var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
       if (dropdownContent.style.display == "none") {
         dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
       } else {
         dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
       }
     });
   }
 },[]);
```

wherever i have class has child
on that element i have to toggle a class active
and on its next siblings , want to add style attr with display

Comment: Not getting what you mean here.

Answer (score 1):

When using a Framework like react that doesn't directly manipulate the DOM it's not recommended to change style like that.
What you should do instead is to either work with classes and toggle them in react, not using `document.getElementsByClassName` or similar functions.

This could look something like this, depending on your need:

```
const ToggleButton = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  return (
    <button onClick={() => setActive(prev => !prev)} className={active ? 'active' : 'inactive'}>
      Toggle active
    </button>

  );
};
```

This component would render a button that can be clicked to toggle between the classes `active` and `inactive`. The rest can and perhaps should be done with purely CSS.

Modern CSS combinators like `~` can be used to affect following elements. You can read more about CSS combinators [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#combinators)

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes this is working but it adds active class on my all the button at once..

Comment: @shashiverma It shouldn't add the `active` class but `inactive` to all buttons until you click on them. You could change `active? 'active' : 'inactive'` to `active && 'active'` to not have an `inactive` class